# Pegando ids de um HTML e jogando para um array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5, array

Eu tenho um formulário bem grande em HTML e gostaria de pegar os ids e guarda-los em um array JavaScript, e depois acessa-los aplicando as regras (tipo nome vazio; inválido.)

**HTML**

```
<form id="formulario" name="formulario" method="POST" href="#">

                <div class="row">

                  <div class="col l3 offset-l3">

                    <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
                    <input 
                     type="text"
                     name="name"
                     id="name"
                     placeholder="Nome">

                  </div>

                  <div class="col l3">

                    <label for="sobrenome">Sobrenome:</label>
                    <input 
                    type="text"
                    name="lastName" 
                    id="lastName" 
                    placeholder="Sobrenome">

                  </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row">

                  <div class="col l3 offset-l3">

                    <label for="idade">Idade:</label>
                    <input 
                     type="text"
                     placeholder="Idade"
                     name="age"
                     id="age">

                  </div>

                  <div class="col l3">

                    <label for="sexo">Sexo:</label>
                    <input 
                     type="radio"
                     name="sex"
                     id="male"/>
                    <label for="masculino">Masculino</label>

                    <input 
                     type="radio"
                     name="sex"
                     id="female"/>
                    <label for="feminino">Feminino</label>

                  </div>

                </div>

                  <div class="row">

                    <div class="col l3 offset-l3">

                      <label for="cep">Cep:</label>
                      <input 
                       type="text"
                       name="cep"
                       id="cep"
                       placeholder="CEP">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col l2">

                      <label for="rua">Rua:</label>
                      <input type="text"
                        name="street"
                        id="street"
                        placeholder="Rua">

                    </div>

                    <div class="col l2">

                        <label for="bairro">Bairro:</label>
                        <input 
                        type="text" 
                        name="neighborhood" 
                        id="neighborhood" 
                        placeholder="Bairro">

                    </div>

                    <div class="col l1">

                      <label for="numero">Número:</label>
                      <input 
                       type="text"
                       name="numberHome"
                       id="numberHome"
                       placeholder="Nº">

                    </div>

                  </div>

                  <div class="row">

                    <div class="col l3 offset-l3">

                      <label for="cidade">Cidade:</label>
                      <input 
                      type="text"
                      name="city"
                      id="city"
                      placeholder="Cidade">

                    </div>

                    <div class="col l1">

                      <label for="estado">Estado:</label>
                      <input 
                       type="text"
                       name="state"
                       id="state"
                       placeholder="Estado">

                    </div>

                    <div class="col l3">

                        <label for="nacionalidade">Nacionalidade:</label>
                      <input 
                      type="text"
                      name="nationality"
                      id="nationality"
                      placeholder="Nacionalidade">

                    </div>

                  </div>

                  <div class="row">

                    <div class="col l7 offset-l3">

                      <label>Formação Acadêmica</label>

                      <textarea
                       id="formation"
                       name="formation"
                       class="materialize-textarea"
                       data-length="200"
                       placeholder="Digite a(s) instituições que você formou">
                    </textarea>

                    </div>

                  </div>

                  <div class="row">

                    <div class="col l7 offset-l3">

                      <label>Cursos Extracurriculares</label>
                      <textarea
                      id="courses"
                      name="courses"
                      class="materialize-textarea"
                      data-length="200"
                      placeholder="Cursos que diferenciam seu currículo">
                      </textarea>

                    </div>

                  </div>


                  <div class="row">

                    <div class="col l6 offset-l3">

                      <input type="checkbox"
                       class="filled-in"
                       id="filled-in-box"
                       checked="checked"
                       />
                      <label for="filled-in-box">Aceito termos de uso</label>

                    </div>

                  </div>

                  <div class="row">

                    <div class="col l6 offset-l3">

                      <input 
                       type="checkbox"
                       class="filled-in" 
                       id="filled-in-box-2" 
                       checked="checked" />
                      <label for="filled-in-box-2">Possuo ciência que empresas possuem minhas informações</label>

                    </div>

                  </div>

                  <div class="row">

                    <div class="col l7 offset-l4">

                    <button 
                      class="btn cta"
                      name="buttonAccept"
                      id="buttonAccept">
                      Desejo participar do banco de talentos
                    </button>

                    </div>

                  </div>

              </form>
```

**JS**

```
window.onload = () => {

    const name = document.getElementById('name')
    const lastName = document.getElementById('lastName')
    const age = document.getElementById('age')
    const sex = document.getElementById('sex')
    const cep = document.getElementById('cep')
    const street = document.getElementById('street')
    const neighborhood = document.getElementById('neighborhood')
    const numberHome = document.getElementById('numberHome')
    const city = document.getElementById('city')
    const state = document.getElementById('state')
    const nationality = document.getElementById('nationality')
    const formation = document.getElementById('formation')
    const courses = document.getElementById('courses')

}
```

Só tentando esclarecer se é possível pegar essas constantes e jogar tudo em um array, e depois acessa-las individualmente para aplicar as condições

edit 1 : Não sei se é o jeito de se fazer, mas eu abri um array chamado

```
var dados = [document.getElementById('nomeDoElemento'), n]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voce disse que queria por os ids no array, então aqui vai

```js
function mostrar(){
 var todasTags = [];
 var ids = document.body.getElementsByTagName('input');//pegando todas as tags input
 for (var i = 0; i< ids.length; i++) {
  todasTags.push(ids[i].id);//adicinando o id no array, conforme a posição
 }
   
 console.log(todasTags);//exibindo
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Teste</title>
</head>
<body>
 
<form>
 <input id="i1" type="text" name="nome">
 <input id="i2" type="text" name="rua">
</form>
<button onclick="mostrar();">mostrar</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mas eu consigo normalmente acessar cada item do array separado certo?

Comment: @Devprogramacao sim, só basta especificar a posição

Comment: Poxa, que legal @Henrique, não tinha pensado nessa lógica. Obrigado, resolveu meu problema.

Comment: @Devprogramacao não há de que